# Ubuntu 19.10 - Add transparency to Files (Nautilus, and other apps) on a permanent basis

Tags: files

I wand to add transparency especially to Files (Nautilus) and other apps as well.. While there are Gnome plugins through Firefox that allow to do so for Terminal, I want a working solution that does so for Nautilus

Answer (score 1):

**1. BY POINTING AT THE APP** (ONLY WORKS FOR ONE INSTANCE)

*Point & click at the app you want to test the transparency of after entering this code in terminal:*

```
sh -c 'xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * 80 / 100)))'
```

Source: [Tips on Ubuntu](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/12/make-app-window-transparent-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/)

**2. WITH DEVILSPIE** (WORKING WALTHROUGH FOR UBUNTU 19.10)

Source: revamped walkthrough from [Emmanuel N Kyeyune](https://dev.to/emmanuelnk/how-to-be-cool-and-make-vscode-transparent-56ib) that left me wondering how to make it work in practice for Nautilus

*2.1. Install DevilsPie and create a config file:*

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
mkdir -p ~/.devilspie
nano ~/.devilspie/nautilus_transparent.ds
```

*2.2. In the above .ds config file enter the following:*

The crucial element is the right app name: [see here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1029261) how to, if you wonder why it's not working with another app, for instance. use `xprop` and find then use the second argument of `WM_CLASS(STRING) =`

```
( if
( begin
( is ( application_name ) "org.gnome.Nautilus" )
)
( begin
;; this is for minimizing the window for testing purposes
;;(minimize)
( spawn_async (str "xprop -id " (window_xid) " -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0xdfffffff") )
)
)
```

*2.3. Normally devilspie detects the config file automatically:*

So run and leave the terminal window busy:

```
devilspie
```

And your Nautilus window will be transparent 80%

To change the transparency simply change your setting in the config file: you want 70% instead, replace 87/100 to 80/100

In terminal, for instance, paste:

```
printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * 80 / 100))
```

Whose value will give you what hexadecimal value to paste inside the argument in the script, in this case: `0xcccccccc` (thus 80% transparency, for instance)

*2.4. Now configure devilspie to start at startup automatically:*

Startup applications > Add > Name: DevilsPie Command: devilspie

And you're done!

Please note [devilspie2](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/205/Tutorial-Devilspie2) exists as well, and uses a [different scripting syntax](https://dev.to/brpaz/take-control-of-your-application-windows-on-linux-with-devilspie-f55) and *.lua config files, I have now tested it successfully:

**3. WITH DEVILSPIE2** (WORKING WALTHROUGH FOR UBUNTU 19.10)

*3.1. Install Devilspie2 and Lua scripting language*

```
sudo apt-get install -y devilspie2 lua5.2
```

*3.2. Edit config file as follows (same as for DevilsPie but it is a .lua file)*

```
if get_application_name()=="org.gnome.Nautilus" then
    set_window_opacity(0.85)
    -- comment for testing
end
```

I used the same directory than for devilspie (1), same filename but with a .lua extension.
Please note that the transparency is from O (transparent) to 1 (opaque). Use a . as decimal divider.

*3.3. Running DevilsPie2:*

Don't forget to indicate which directory devilspie2 has to search for it's config files, by running

```
devilspie2 -f ~/.devilspie/
```

And once again, it's working. This version is simpler, including to configure. DevilsPie2 goes and search into the specified dir for .lua config files/scripts.

*3.4 Starting DevilsPie2 at startup*

See 2.4, but don't forget to specify the command line arguments as of 3.3!

Enjoy!

Note: Thanks to the [Lua community](https://www.lua.org/community.html) that is well organized and has an [IRC#](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IrcChannel) which sypathetically helped me to find the right solution to make everything work adapting the script!

Comment: for devilspie2 create a *SINGLE* config file and name it like *apps.lua* to put all your applications u wish to be transparent.

Comment: xprop WM_CLASS // google-chrome | devilspie2 doesn't work with google-chrome in my case but with other apps it does